# How to limit the categories shown in a count graph based on whether there is data?

Tags: python

My data has two categorical variables:

- 5 function
- 35 diploma

df = pd.DataFrame({'function': ['nurse', 'doctor', 'paediatric_nurse','kitchen_staff','surgeon'], 
                   'diploma': ['nurse_schoolA', 'nurse_schoolB, ...'nurse_school M, doctor_schoolA'....]})

For each function, I want a graph showing a count of each diploma.

```
ax=sns.catplot(x='ldiploma',kind='count',data=df,orient="h", col='function')
ax.fig.autofmt_xdate()
```

Is there a way to limit the data shown for each function to only the diploma for which there is data in this category?

I tried the following, which results in an error message that df is not recognized

```
ax=sns.catplot(x='diploma',kind='count',data=df.query("df['diploma'].count()>0"),orient="h", col='function')
ax.fig.autofmt_xdate()
```

[image]

[df.head()](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mk2kG.png)
[df.heqd() diploma](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xf0jS.png)

Comment: Can you share a sample of your data ? and showing the full error message ?

Comment: ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\computation\scope.py in resolve(self, key, is_local)
    180             if self.has_resolvers:
--> 181                 return self.resolvers[key]
    182 

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\collections\__init__.py in __missing__(self, key)
    905     def __missing__(self, key):
--> 906         raise KeyError(key)
    907 

KeyError: 'df'

Comment: The error comes from `data=df.query("df['diploma'].count()>0")`. Python understands `df` as a column name of your dataframe. Sharing a sample of the data will help to understand how it is structured. Also, it's better to *edit* the question instead of answering long piece of code/error in comments.

Comment: Thank you, I am quite a novice here :)

Comment: You might try to define the count per diploma in a variable: `d = df['diploma'].count()` and then plotting `data = d[d > 0]` ? Without data sample, it's hard to guess. I advice you to have a look at [*How to make good reproducible pandas examples*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples)

Comment: that doesn't work - then d would be a constant. I need d to varry depending on the diploma category and the function

Comment: Can you share the result of `df.head(20)` ?